# ConstraintViolationException won't be thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, constraintviolationexception

When I launch my request, the ConstraintViolationException does not want to be thrown for a field with a regex in the contract

> Here the request in postman

```
apiName/v1/account?cardNumer=55^fields=customerName
```

> Here the contract AccountApi with a regex on the field cardNumber

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{6}[A-Z][0-9]{9}$") @Parameter(name = "cardNumber")
```

> Here the Controller.java with the @Validated annotation
>
> The AccountController .java implements AccountApi which is the contract

```
@RestController
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class AccountController implements AccountApi {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<Account>> getAccount(String cardNumer) {
    }
}
```

> Here the AccountControllerExceptionHandler.java with the ConstraintViolationException

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AccountControllerExceptionHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public Error manageErrorRegexViolation(final ConstraintViolationException e, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.error("Error ConstraintViolationException {}.", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

- The regex in the contract for the field cardNumber is here
- The @Validated annotation in the Controller is here
- The ConstraintViolationException in the ExceptionHandler.java is here

In others threads they only said to add thoses 3 things

Answer (score 0):

mvn clean package then in Intelij invalidates caches and maven/reimport and it works !